# SQL PIVOT SELECT FROM LIST (IN SELECT)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

Is it possible to do a PIVOT and select list from a table, instead of using single values?

Like this (incorrect syntax error):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT RepID, MilestoneID, ResultID FROM RM
) AS src
PIVOT (
    MAX(ResultID) FOR MilestoneID IN  (SELECT id FROM m) 
) AS pvt
```

This one compiles, but doesn't work for me:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT RepID, MilestoneID, ResultID FROM RM
) AS src
PIVOT (
    MAX(ResultID) FOR MilestoneID IN  ([1], [2], [3], [4]) 
) AS pvt
```

PS: I do NOT want to use dynamic SQL, is there a way to do this without using dynamic SQL?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately you need to specific the values in the `IN` clause. You could use dynamic SQL to inspect the values and then execute the resulting statement.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If dynamic SQL is out then I'm afraid the answer is no, it can't be done. The parser needs to know the values up front to perform the pivot to columns.

Comment: Why doesn't the parser know the values up front?  It could complete the `SELECT` query first.

Answer (score 10):

It Can be done.

```
DECLARE @idList varchar(500)
SELECT @idList = COALESCE(@idList + ',', '') + id
FROM m


DECLARE @sqlToRun varchar(1000)
SET @sqlToRun = '
SELECT * 
FROM ( 
    SELECT RepID, MilestoneID, ResultID FROM RM 
) AS src 
PIVOT ( 
    MAX(ResultID) FOR MilestoneID IN  ('+ @idList +')  
) AS pvt'   

EXEC (@sqlToRun)
```

Comment: Thats what the point is. CoderGal doesnt want to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: It may not help the poster, but it helped to remind me that its possible! so +1

Comment: Where does rm come from? Some sample data along would have helped this example.

Comment: Great solution. Thanks. I think that second line should be a `SELECT`, not a `SET`.